# Load templates, pass arguments, and render output from functions.php

Tags: functions, shortcode, templates, get-template-part

I can't seem to find a solution to actually loading a template, passing arguments to it, executing it, and displaying the results from a shortcode registered via `functions.php`

Is this even possible? I would like to have editable template parts that are not hard-coded into the function. I tried output buffer, but it still doesn't get anything from the `get_template_parts()` functions, so I had to return to outputting HTML from the function.

Edit: Would it be appropriate to just include/require the files, and capture them with output buffer? Is that appropriate for WordPress?

Comment: There’s no reason output buffering wouldn’t work with `get_template_part()` (note the singular “part”). It’s hard to say what might be wrong without seeing code though.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.